# typescript: "narrowing" a union type to one of its component

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Suppose I have this union type:

```
type Foo = {tag: 'A', name: string} | {tag: 'B', value: number}
```

I am trying to write a function that gets a tag value (`'A' | 'B'`) and then does some business-specific lookup in a list of `Foo`s and returns a matching element. For the purpose of this question we can think of this very trivial function:

```
function findFirst(foos: Foo[], tag: 'A' | 'B') {
  for (const foo of foos) {
    if (foo.tag === tag) { 
      return foo 
    }
  }
  return undefined
}
```

Suppose I now call this function passing 'A' as the second argument. It is clear that it either returns `undefined` or a `{tag: 'A', name: string}` object. It just cannot return a `{tag: 'B', value: number}` in this situation.

Still, the TSC does not seem to be able to infer this. When writing an expression such as:

```
findFirst([{tag: 'A', name: 'X'}], 'A')?.name
```

The TSC errors with `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Foo'.`.

I am guessing that I need to help the compiler infer the right by expliticly defining the return type of `findFirst()` but I am not sure how.

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvYBDA5gLigcgEF8AaKAOwwFsI8BnYAJwEtysBfKAHzU1wIBCpKADcMAGwCutCpKoAjCI3YAoFQDNJ5AMbBmcclHWsAJjGaMGACnUI6eeHADaAXTJ88RfN0H4AlGgqUEZwjFBW2gYMIYhw6jF0AahBwVDM8TYIAHR8yEgofElQKalQjBDAkoyGtoglUKrBjWUVVYZaJhDG5BAmKqpqGqbmlsBWTujYnsRklDSeABr47G4ExH4A-FlzEGpAA))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a type parameter to the function to capture the actual type of tag being passed in. You then need to filter the `Foo` union using the `Extract` predefined conditional type:

```
function findFirst<T extends Foo['tag']>(foos: Foo[], tag: T) {
  for (const foo of foos) {
    if (foo.tag === tag) { 
      return foo as Extract<Foo, { tag: T }>
    }
  }
  return undefined
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvYBDA5gLigcgEF8AaKAOwwFsI8BnYAJwEtysBfKAHzU1wIBCpKADcMAGwCutCpKoAjCI3YAoFQDNJ5AMbBmcclHWsAJjGaMGAHgAqUCAA9gEcibqwEAbXx98AXQA+AAp1BDo8eDhPPzI+PBsASjQVKCM4Rigg7QMGNMQ4dTy6JNQU1KhmQpCEADo+ZCQUPhKoMvKoRghgSUZDUMQMdwBRJ0YMXStIslQoOKg7dgC2qFVU1Y6unsMtEwhjcggTFVU1DVNzS2Agz3RsPCJhShp7gA18dhiCYgSAfhqniBnVwXBjXW78B5kAGvd6ffBCX41MRSQEqIA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#writing-good-overloads) to declare the result without having to use cast.

```
type FooA = {tag: 'A', name: string};
type FooB = {tag: 'B', value: number};

type Foo = FooA | FooB 

function findFirst(foos: Foo[], tag: 'A'): FooA | undefined;
function findFirst(foos: Foo[], tag: 'B'): FooB | undefined;
function findFirst(foos: Foo[], tag: 'A' | 'B') {
  for (const foo of foos) {
    if (foo.tag === tag) { 
      return foo 
    }
  }
  return undefined
}


findFirst([{tag: 'A', name: 'X'}], 'A')?.name
findFirst([{tag: 'A', name: 'X'}], 'B')?.value

// TS Error as expected
findFirst([{tag: 'A', name: 'X'}], 'A')?.value
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAglAvFA3sAhgcwFxQDkihANFAHZYC2EBAzsAE4CWFOAvgNwBQoksBACFUGbPiJCyUAG5YANgFc6lRdQBGEJtx59w0eHFGHkAH0FwRugGaKKAY2As4FKNbYATGCyaMAFNYI9ASGANoAuuTiBMSEAJQhCGZQdh4Q7hQQHry2Dk4ubp7evsABQYlwEVG4MVIJFiLmqelsWTl2js6uGV4+-oFwwRZVUNFEJFDmhHUYPFBucExQfvYujAtGcNYb9HGz8-Ms22VwAHTiqCho4nvoUHMH80wQwIpM3Qj3jxwPP08vb1czQyWR4PxsRT6pVCmBq42kVFoMQAGoQOJF4XEAPynREQHg9Yr+GFjWLkPEotEY6bxHFyJT4ngAeiZUAAKgBlKAAUSYTEWBMhJT8JLhZMoNBUhFR6PIsWxp3pyh4QA)